# How to scroll fixed view up while scrolling gridview below?

Tags: android

[The marked area should scroll up while sliding up the gridview contentsand should get back to position while I reach back to top while sliding down the gridview items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUeIe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set a scroll listener on the GridView and then manually scroll the fixed View.

```
myGridView.setOnScrollListener( new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // Scroll the fixed view here
    }
});
```